# Scipy solve_ivp extremely slow/freezing

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I have been working on a problem that involves solving 2 pairs of coupled ode's. It has been recommended that we use scipy solve_ivp to do this however it seems to be either freezing or running extremely slowly (I have ran this for up to half an hour with no results).

I have limited experience with solving ode's numerically and have never used solve_ivp before so this could be a simple error but I have been unable to find it.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate as sc

param_dict = {
    'r1': 0.36,
    'r2': 0.15,
    'k1': 4000000,
    'b12': 0.0000002,
    'b21': 0.69,
    'p1': 80,
    'p2': 275,
    'q1': 0.0002,
    'q2': 0.0004,
    'phi1': 0.00095,
    'phi2': 0.000075,
    'c1': 20000,
    'c2': 30000
}

# INITIAL VALUES
init_X = np.array([4000000,275000])
init_E = np.array([800,200])
y0 = np.concatenate((init_X, init_E))

def functions(t, X, r1, r2, k1, b12, b21, q1, q2, phi1, phi2, c1, c2, p1, p2):
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = X
    dx1dt = (r1 * x1) * (1 - (x1 / k1) - (b12 * x2)) - (q1 * y1 * x1)
    dx2dt = (r2 * x2) * (1 - (x2 / (b21 * x1))) - (q2 * y2 * x2)
    dy1dt = phi1 * y1 * (p1*q1 * x1 - c1)
    dy2dt = phi2 * y2 * (p2*q2 * x2 - c2)
    return [dx1dt, dx2dt, dy1dt, dy2dt]

t_span = [0,20]
t = np.linspace(0,100,1000)

res = sc.solve_ivp(functions, t_span, y0, args=tuple(param_dict.values()), dense_output=True)

zz = res.sol(t)
x1 = []
x2 = []
e1 = []
e2 = []
for ii in range(len(zz.T)):
    x1.append(zz.T[ii,0])
    x2.append(zz.T[ii,1])
    e1.append(zz.T[ii,2])
    e2.append(zz.T[ii,3])

plt.plot(x1)
plt.plot(x2)
```

If I set `init_E = [0,0]` it runs seemingly as expected however any other value here seems to lead to this freezing/extremely slow problem.

The model here describes a predator/prey model for fisheries management for those interested.

Comment: You do know that t_span only goes up to 20, but you want a solution for t up to 100? Anyway, if I change tspan and ```plt.plot(t,x1);   plt.plot(t,x2);   plt.show()``` I can't reproduce your problem: the solution looks fine and takes microseconds. Remember that you need ```plt.show()``` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be that the keys in your dictionary are not in the same order as the arguments to your function.

If I do the following it solves immediately.

```
param_names = ['r1', 'r2', 'k1', 'b12', 'b21', 'q1', 'q2', 'phi1', 
               'phi2', 'c1', 'c2', 'p1', 'p2']
args = tuple(param_dict[p] for p in param_names)
res = sc.solve_ivp(functions, t_span, y0, args=args, dense_output=True)
```

(Not sure if this is the correct solution but it doesn't hang up).

Bit of advice:

- In general it's always good to make at least one call to your function and verify its output before passing it to a solver.  E.g. at the initial condition like this:

```
f0 = functions(0, y0, *args)
assert np.array_equal(f0, [-719200.0, 15139.945652173912, 33440.0, 3.75])
```

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the problem, it ended up plugging in huge values for what should have been tiny values which seems to have been causing the issue.